# Can you use awk to print and write to file in jupyter ?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

In jupyter notebook I've written the following:

```
%awk -F\\t 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"}{print $1,$2}' /path/to/file.txt > /output/file.txt
```

Howver the file is not created. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bang instead of `%`:

```
!awk -F\\t 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"}{print $1,$2}' /path/to/file.txt > /output/file.txt
```